# i want to do a change in the html evry time the user do a mouseclick randomly in the page

Tags: javascript, dom

as a practice,i want:
evry time user click or press a  key randomly in the screen(empty places) do an action.
  tried that with
       `document.addEventListener("event",function());` 

but it do the change only once.
for exemple:
a variable showed on the screen in evry click on the screen it add 1 to it.
or when a user tape in an empty page something with keyboard it show up in screen.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", test);

function test() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World!";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: If you add an event listener with `document.addEventListener` it should run every time the event occurs, not just once. You need to post your full code so we can see why it's not working correctly.

Comment: Make sure you don't have `()` after the function name when you call `addEventListener`. The argument should be a reference to the function, you shouldn't call it immediately.

Comment: @Barmar for  exemple       `aaddEventListener("click", test);
function test(){ document.write("Hello World!");}`   it write hello world only once after refresh  not add it evry time

Comment: Don't use `document.write()` after the page has loaded. That wipes out the entire DOM.

Comment: `document.addEventListener('click', () => {
  /* do your changes here*/
});

document.addEventListener('keydown', () => {
  /* do your changes here*/
});`

Comment: @Barmar what to use then ? `document.innerHTML` give the same result,only once too

Comment: @MiroslavGlamuzina yea it do the change only one time after refresh

Comment: Modify a specific element, e.g. `document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Hello world";`

Comment: @Barmar exactly,i tried it and the same only once aftre refresh ,i want the change in evry click

Comment: That shouldn't happen. You must be doing something wrong. But unless you post your real code, there's no way for us to know what you're doing.

Comment: @Barmar take the code and try it `<p id="demo"></p>
<script>
addEventListener("click", test);
function test(){ 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="Hello World!";
  
}`

Comment: How can you tell whether the second click is doing anything, it's putting the same text in the element? So you won't see any change.

Comment: Try `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="<br>Hello World!";` That will add another line to it.

Comment: @Barmar thank you miste barmar for your help it's ok

Comment: writing function in `document.addEventListener` u adviced me earlier to write it with out () ? what is the deffirent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you click the first time, the second click makes the same change to the DOM, so you won't see any difference. Make it assign something different so you can see the change.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", test);
var counter = 0;
function test() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World! " + counter;
  counter++;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```